# Unable to get appropriate Input validation for Integer

Tags: c++

```
double age = 0;
int empAge;

cout << "Please enter your age in integers: ";
cin >> age;

// Input validation for age. To prevent input with a decimal number eg 5.6, 7.8, 90.9, etc

while(cin.fail() || ((int)age != (double)age)){
    cout << "\nThat is not a valid option, please try again. ";
    cin >> age; 

    if(cin.fail() || (int)age != double(age)){
        cin.clear();
        string not_an_int;
        cin >> not_an_int;
    }
    cout << "That is not a valid option, please try again. ";
    cin >> age;
}
// Assigns the data in variable of double type age to the variable of int type empAge   
age = empAge;
```

What I need to get done ?
Ask user to enter a integer digit only.
If not an integer give error "That is not a valid option, please try again" and ask user to enter again.

Attached is also an image showing errors my code gives with the inputs used.

[image]

Comment: You probably want to call `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` right after `cin.clear()` instead of `string not_an_int` etc.

Comment: "_Attached is also an image showing errors my code gives with the inputs used._" Don't post images of text. Copy-paste text into the question, as text.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. Please clarify your question. What is the problem?

Comment: Reading the comments in your code, I think you are supposed to do something like  `int tmp_age; cin >> tmp_age; ... // check for input fails ... double age = tmp_age;`, which would make the last assignment (or comment) to have sense.

Comment: @KorelK Apologies for the ambiguity. Basically i need the user to input a integer value, if it is not an integer then give error. Keep repeating until user enters an integer value.

Just trying to remove bad input such as alphabets, decimal numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I need to get done ? Ask user to enter a integer digit only. If
>   not an integer give error "That is not a valid option, please try
>   again" and ask user to enter again.

I advise you to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) carefully, as it is quite unclear what exactly you are asking.

I've prepared this small snippet for you in case you are asking something like *How do I read user input using `stdin` while validating it is only an integer value?*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

bool is_natural(const std::string s)
{
    return s.find_first_not_of( "0123456789" ) == std::string::npos;
}

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    while (!(std::cin >> input) || !is_natural(input))
    {
        std::cout << "That is not a valid option, please try again.\n";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    int age = std::stoi(input);
    std::cout << "Age (natural integer value) entered: " << age << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read only integers in input, this is a possible solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int age;
    unsigned long status;
    string myString;
    do {
        cout << "Please enter your age in integers: ";
        getline(cin, myString);

        /*
         * Return the position of the first character that does not match.
         * Else return "string::npos"
         */
        status = myString.find_first_not_of("0123456789");

        if (status != string::npos)
            cout << "That is not a valid option, please try again." << endl;
    } while (status != string::npos);

    //Convert string to int.
    age = stoi(myString);

    cout << "Age as integer: " << age << endl;
}
```

You can use **stoi()** only in **c++ 11 or following**:

```
int num = stoi( str )
```

Old method:

```
int num = atoi( str.c_str() )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using namespace std;

// The method check if the string only contains digits
bool is_digits(const std::string &str)
{
    return std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isdigit);
}

int main()
{
    int age;
    bool status = false;
    string myString;
    while (!status) {
        cout << "Please enter your age in integers: ";
        cin >> myString;

        status = is_digits(myString);
        if (!status)
            cout << "That is not a valid option, please try again." << endl;
    }

    //Convert string to int.
    age = stoi(myString);

    cout << "Age as integer: " << age << endl;
    return 0;
}
```